# Julia shell mode in a .jl file

Tags: julia

In REPL mode, Julia lets you type a semicolon and run shell commands, i.e.

```
;
cd ~
```

And then  to return to Julian REPL

Is there a way to do something similar in a .jl file? The closest I found was `run(…)` and that has many caveats.  This is a Linux environment, so I'm not concerned about the caveats of shell mode on Windows machines.

The broader topic of interest is in doing this for other REPL modes, like the R one provided by `using RCall`

Comment: What caveats does `run` have that are getting in your way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the default way to do is via the `run` command. If you have not already, check out the docs on this https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/running-external-programs/#Running-External-Programs which go into some of the caveats.

I am not sure I follow what you are getting at with `RCall` but it may perhaps be worth opening a separate question for that.

Comment: I think he means that with `RCall` you can either type `$` for new prompt but you can also directly use `R` via the `R""` string macro.

Comment: The string macro is the solution for RCall, and I guess that using `run` is the recommended solution for shell

Answer (score 1):

You can find the code for this at https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/tree/master/stdlib/REPL/test.

Seems there is no API, just lots of typing.

Here is a minimal working example (the codes are mostly copied from different places from the folder above):

```
using REPL
mutable struct FakeTerminal <: REPL.Terminals.UnixTerminal
    in_stream::Base.IO
    out_stream::Base.IO
    err_stream::Base.IO
    hascolor::Bool
    raw::Bool
    FakeTerminal(stdin,stdout,stderr,hascolor=true) =
        new(stdin,stdout,stderr,hascolor,false)
end

REPL.Terminals.hascolor(t::FakeTerminal) = t.hascolor
REPL.Terminals.raw!(t::FakeTerminal, raw::Bool) = t.raw = raw
REPL.Terminals.size(t::FakeTerminal) = (24, 80)

input = Pipe()
output = Pipe()
err = Pipe()
Base.link_pipe!(input, reader_supports_async=true, writer_supports_async=true)
Base.link_pipe!(output, reader_supports_async=true, writer_supports_async=true)
Base.link_pipe!(err, reader_supports_async=true, writer_supports_async=true)
repl = REPL.LineEditREPL(FakeTerminal(input.out, output.in, err.in, false), false)

repltask = @async REPL.run_repl(repl)
```

Now you can do:

```
julia> println(input,";ls -la *.jld2")

-rw-r--r-- 1 pszufe 197121 5506 Jul  5  2020 file.jld2
-rw-r--r-- 1 pszufe 197121 5506 Jul  5  2020 myfile.jld2
```